# Why can't I access option groups?

Tags: error, admin, settings, option

Drupal 7
Civicrm 4.74

Receiving this error:

API permission check failed for Case/getcount call; insufficient permission: require Array

CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "API permission check failed for Case/getcount call; insufficient permission: require Array"

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php(1914): civicrm_api3("Case", "getcount", (Array:1))
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(294): CRM_Case_BAO_Case::caseCount(NULL, FALSE)
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(251): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->action(Object(CRM_Core_BAO_OptionGroup), 10, (Array:7), (Array:4), 1)
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Options.php(232): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->browse()
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(172): CRM_Admin_Page_Options->browse(NULL, NULL)
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Options.php(224): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Admin_Page_Options->run((Array:3), NULL)
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
[internal function](): civicrm_invoke("admin", "options")
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
{main}
 Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
API permission check failed for Case/getcount call; insufficient permission: require Array
Return to home page.
```

Comment: Can you give more info about when you see this?  If you turn on debugging/backtrace, do you get more information?

Comment: Hm. Comment box is too short for the full debug. - see addition to original question above.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I didn't answer your question. I get this error when clicking on Administer > System Settings > Option Groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in CiviCRM 4.7 which has now been fixed. See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18456

Answer (score 1):

OK, I ended up getting into a rabbit hole and spending more time than expected here!

There's a short workaround for you, if you're not trying to edit CiviCase-related option groups:  Comment out CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php line 294, which reads:

```
$caseCount = CRM_Case_BAO_Case::caseCount(NULL, FALSE);
```

For the in-depth fix, I've opened a new bug on issues.civicrm.org [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18309).